# How do I work with Set and Custom Classes?

Tags: c++, class, oop, collections, set

I did think until now that it would be a good idea to create a collection of ingredients in order to get something line a list of all possible ingedients gor my stock. And to compare this stock with the needed ingedients. This way I want to reduce the amount of ingedients in the stock.

Ingedients (zutat) is one class that contains a string name and a double for quantity.

The set should contain the ingedient. 
Set

Till know I got many errors. The linker error I could solve be write in a new project.

But I do not like my zutat class. Since it seems to work only as long as I have public attributes and not private attributes that I could call with getter and set with setter. In my opinion this public attributes go against oop.

I did overload bool operator< to conpare only the name of the ingedient. Since I do not want more than one inside the stock.

But now I am stuck ... I did think that I could get the class back to change the quantity value. But with find I get only the iterator back if the name is equal. 
I did think it would be possible to get the element back in order to work with the element of the stack. Than remove this element from the stack since this values are constant and to insert the value again after I did change the quantitiy.

If it isn't possible to work with the elements inside of a set or to at least get them back. Why should you even use it?

What would you recommend to use in order to get me a collection of ingedients without duplicates where I could change the values.

Comment: You could use a std::map with the name of the ingredient as the key. You could also mark the quantity of your ingredient as mutable and keep using the set. You could store smart pointers in the set.

Comment: Than it is good that bruno could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than to use a *std::set* just use a *std::map*, like `std::map<std::string, int>`, the key is the name of the ingredient and the value the amount of the ingredient.

That allows you to quickly get the amount of an ingredient from its name, or to modify an amount.

When the amount of an ingredient become 0 you can remove it from the *map* if you want, to only have in it the ingredient you have in your stock

Of course you can replace the amount by more having for instance `std::map<std::string, Ingredient>` where the class *Ingredient* have amount and other information like may be again the name of the ingredient.

Comment: This was my second idea. But I need the ingedient without a list in some other parts. This way I did use ingedient as a class of its own.

Comment: @ChiruKaio If you prefer you can replace the value (_int_) by an instance or pointer to of a class containing more that just the amount. I am pretty sure you need to find an ingredient from its name, the _map_ helps you a lot for that, it also support the list of ingredients without needing an other collection elsewhere

Comment: You mean that I create a map where I set the first value to the the ingedient, and the second value would be the instance of the class. This would be wonderful

Comment: @ChiruKaio, to have `std::map<std::string, Ingredient>` where Ingredient is a class may be with the name again, the amount, etc The key is still the name